# mysql GROUP BY if this row table.filed > 0

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements

how i can `GROUP BY entry_category` `if`   `entry_category > 0`

```
| entry_id | entry_title | entry_category |
-------------------------------
| 1        | xxx         | 6       |
| 2        | xxx         | 4       |
| 3        | xxx         | 6       |
| 4        | xxx         | 0       |
| 5        | xxx         | 0       |
| 6        | xxx         | 6       |
| 7        | xxx         | 4       |
| 8        | xxx         | 7       |
```

I want  entrys  category is set , **not show duplicate** :

```
| 1        | xxx         | 6       |
| 2        | xxx         | 4       |
| 4        | xxx         | 0       |
| 5        | xxx         | 0       |
| 8        | xxx         | 7       |
```

Comment: Related to the `entry_id`, do you want the _first_ (minimum) `entry_id` per grouped `entry_category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, but there may be better way to do it. I took table name as `test`

```
select 
entry_id,
entry_title,
entry_category
from
(
  (
    select
    t1.entry_id,
    t1.entry_title,
    t1.entry_category
    from test t1
    left join test t2
    on t1.entry_category = t2.entry_category
    AND t1.entry_id < t2.entry_id
    where t1.entry_category <> 0 
    group by t1.entry_category
  )
  union all
  (
    select entry_id,entry_title,entry_category from test 
    where entry_category = 0
  )
)x
order by entry_id
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d91/14)**

Answer (score 0):

this is  very good worked for me :

```
    SELECT * FROM entrys 
    WHERE entry_category> 0
    GROUP BY  entry_category
  UNION
    SELECT * FROM entrys 
    WHERE entry_category= 0
```

**good worked.**